# Hadoop 2.6.0: Basic error "starting MRAppMaster" after installing

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have just started to work with Hadoop 2.

After installing with basic configs, I always failed to run any examples. Has anyone seen this problem and please help me?

And the error is something like

```
Error starting MRAppMaster
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

This is the log

```
20152015-01-06 11:56:23,194 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Created MRAppMaster for application appattempt_1420510526926_0002_000001
2015-01-06 11:56:23,362 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:131)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:66)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:280)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:271)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(UserGroupInformation.java:299)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1473)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1429)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:129)
... 7 more

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.anchorNative()V
at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.anchorNative(Native Method)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.<clinit>(JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:49)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.<init>(JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.java:39)
... 12 more

2015-01-06 11:56:23,366 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Error messages:** "Error starting MRAppMaster", "InvocationTargetException", "UnsatisfiedLinkError"

**Root cause:** Fail to execute the native function "anchorNative" in the class "org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping"

**Description:** the function "anchorNative" will call a function in the library "libhadoop.so". The path of this library is specified by these environment variables:

```
export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR
```

In the Hadoop source code, print the java library class path by

```
System.err.println( (System.getProperty("java.library.path") );

# result
/home/maidinh/hadoop2/build/hadoop-2.6.0-src/hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-2.6.0/lib/native:
/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:
/usr/lib64:
/lib64:
/lib:
/usr/lib
```

Different versions of the library "libhadoop.so" can be found in these locations that make a conflict.

**Solution:** Except the right path of native library (in hadoop-2.6.0/lib/native), delete all "libhadoop.so" in other directories.

**Notes:** delete all related libraries of hadoop

```
rm -r libhadoop*
rm -r libhdfs*
```

Comment: That was really helpful thanx a lot.. There were conflicting hadoop libraries in /usr/lib64 .