# Error “starting MRAppMaster” running hadoop job on emr

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, emr, amazon-emr

When I'm trying to run a hadoop job on emr cluster, I’m getting the below mentioned error which says failed to launch because of "AM Container” and on looking into the container logs, I could see that it fails while starting “MRAppMaster”.On local developer desktop I’m able to run the job successfully.

I have searched on web and found this([Hadoop 2.6.0: Basic error "starting MRAppMaster" after installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791518/hadoop-2-6-0-basic-error-starting-mrappmaster-after-installing)) , which says this issue can be because of having multiple versions of hadoop “hadoop.so”. Based on the suggestion mentioned in the stack over flow could fetch the “java.library.path” and my results: 
:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native
Path : /usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native , doesn’t contain any hadoop.so files.
Path : /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native, does contain hadoop.so and hadoop.so.1.0.

I tried deleting one from the later and run my job, but it continued failing with the same error.

Error Message :

Stdlog of my emr job :

2015-11-26 11:18:17,074 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Job job_1448532525181_0004 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1448532525181_0004 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1448532525181_0004_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1448532525181_0004XXX001XXX
Exit code: 1

```
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
2015-11-26 11:18:17,095 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Counters: 0

Container Logs :

```
2015-11-26 10:11:40,020 INFO [main] com.amazonaws.latency: ClientExecuteTime=[44.047], 2015-11-26 10:11:40,021 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceRequest.getDelegationToken()Ljava/lang/String;
at com.amazonaws.handlers.internal.S3SecurityTokenRequestHandler.beforeRequest(S3SecurityTokenRequestHandler.java:33)
at com.amazonaws.handlers.RequestHandler2Adaptor.beforeRequest(RequestHandler2Adaptor.java:37)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.requestHandler2s(AmazonHttpClient.java:434)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:292)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3595)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1041)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:1013)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.ensureBucketExists(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:105)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.initialize(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:86)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.initialize(S3NativeFileSystem.java:466)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.initialize(EmrFileSystem.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2644)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:90)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2678)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2660)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:374)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.<init>(FileOutputCommitter.java:91)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.<init>(FileOutputCommitter.java:74)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.DirectFileOutputCommitter.<init>(DirectFileOutputCommitter.java:31)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.getOutputCommitter(FileOutputFormat.java:310)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FilterOutputFormat.getOutputCommitter(FilterOutputFormat.java:67)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.LazyOutputFormat.getOutputCommitter(LazyOutputFormat.java:92)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:471)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.callWithJobClassLoader(MRAppMaster.java:1542)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.createOutputCommitter(MRAppMaster.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceInit(MRAppMaster.java:371)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$4.run(MRAppMaster.java:1500)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1497)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1430) 2015-11-26 10:11:40,026 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

Any help on this would be of great help and please let me know if you need any more information from my end.

Thanks,
Anusha.K

Comment: This looks like library/dependencies conflicting. Make sure you are building your jar against the same AWS SDK as on the cluster.