# Hadoop Error, Class Not Found

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to run a simple hadoop example on my local cluster on Ubuntu, specifically a word counter.

I created the java class and saved it as a jar, which am then running as:

```
hadoop jar hadoop.jar uk.me.dariosdesk.hadoopTest.TestWordCount /dario/in/ /dario/outb
```

The "in" directory has the file I'm trying to process:

```
dario@dario-X750JB:/usr/local/hadoop$ hadoop fs -ls /dario/in
2018-01-03 00:20:41,172 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 dario supergroup         16 2018-01-02 23:20 /dario/in/test.txt
```

I am however getting the following error:

```
2018-01-03 00:05:31,877 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Full stack:

```
2018-01-03 00:05:31,593 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Created MRAppMaster for application appattempt_1514928906254_0004_000002
2018-01-03 00:05:31,747 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: 
/************************************************************
[system properties]
os.name: Linux
os.version: 3.19.0-25-generic
java.home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
java.runtime.version: 1.8.0_66-b17
java.vendor: Oracle Corporation
java.version: 1.8.0_66
java.vm.name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.class.path: /tmp/hadoop-dario/nm-local-dir/usercache/dario/appcache/application_1514928906254_0004/container_1514928906254_0004_02_000001:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-kms-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.0.0-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.19.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-recipes-2.12.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-asn1-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-identity-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/metrics-core-3.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-annotations-2.7.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-2.7.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/htrace-core4-4.1.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-admin-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-config-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.4.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-io-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-databind-2.7.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-server-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-servlet-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.5.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax2-api-3.1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-framework-2.12.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.54.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/re2j-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-common-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-client-2.12.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-server-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.19.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-security-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-simplekdc-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-util-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-webapp-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/token-provider-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/nimbus-jose-jwt-4.41.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/accessors-smart-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-pkix-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-util-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-xml-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/json-smart-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-http-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration2-2.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-5.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.19.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-xdr-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-crypto-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/woodstox-core-5.0.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-client-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerb-core-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-native-client-3.0.0-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-client-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-client-3.0.0-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-3.0.0-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-native-client-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.19.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/curator-recipes-2.12.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/kerby-asn1-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-ajax-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/kerb-identity-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/hadoop-auth-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-annotations-2.7.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-2.7.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/htrace-core4-4.1.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/kerb-admin-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/kerby-config-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/httpcore-4.4.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-io-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-databind-2.7.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/kerb-server-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-servlet-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/httpclient-4.5.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/stax2-api-3.1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/curator-framework-2.12.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsch-0.1.54.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/re2j-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/kerb-common-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/hadoop-annotations-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/curator-client-2.12.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/okio-1.4.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-server-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.19.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-security-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/kerb-simplekdc-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/kerb-util-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-webapp-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/token-provider-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/nimbus-jose-jwt-4.41.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/accessors-smart-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/avro-1.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/kerby-pkix-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/kerby-util-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-xml-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/json-smart-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-http-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/okhttp-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-configuration2-2.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-5.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-json-1.19.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/kerby-xdr-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/kerb-crypto-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/woodstox-core-5.0.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/kerb-client-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/zookeeper-3.4.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/kerb-core-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-sharedcachemanager-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-timelineservice-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-timelineservice-hbase-tests-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-timeline-pluginstorage-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-timelineservice-hbase-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-router-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/hbase-prefix-tree-1.2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/metrics-core-3.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.7.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-csv-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre7.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-math-2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.19.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/joni-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/hbase-hadoop-compat-1.2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/disruptor-3.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/fst-2.50.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.19.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.7.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/HikariCP-java7-2.4.12.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jamon-runtime-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/hbase-server-1.2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/json-io-2.5.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/findbugs-annotations-1.3.9-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/hbase-client-1.2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/hbase-common-1.2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.7.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/java-util-1.9.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-4.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jcodings-1.0.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/hbase-annotations-1.2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/geronimo-jcache_1.0_spec-1.0-alpha-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/hbase-protocol-1.2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/hbase-procedure-1.2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/hbase-hadoop2-compat-1.2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-4.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/ehcache-3.3.1.jar:/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:job.jar/job.jar:job.jar/classes/:job.jar/lib/*:/tmp/hadoop-dario/nm-local-dir/usercache/dario/appcache/application_1514928906254_0004/container_1514928906254_0004_02_000001/job.jar
java.io.tmpdir: /tmp/hadoop-dario/nm-local-dir/usercache/dario/appcache/application_1514928906254_0004/container_1514928906254_0004_02_000001/tmp
user.dir: /tmp/hadoop-dario/nm-local-dir/usercache/dario/appcache/application_1514928906254_0004/container_1514928906254_0004_02_000001
user.name: dario
************************************************************/
2018-01-03 00:05:31,748 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil: Updating Configuration
2018-01-03 00:05:31,833 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Executing with tokens: [Kind: YARN_AM_RM_TOKEN, Service: , Ident: (appAttemptId { application_id { id: 4 cluster_timestamp: 1514928906254 } attemptId: 2 } keyId: 740497726)]
2018-01-03 00:05:31,857 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2018-01-03 00:05:31,857 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2018-01-03 00:05:31,875 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster failed in state INITED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RecordFactoryPBImpl.newRecordInstance(RecordFactoryPBImpl.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.Records.newRecord(Records.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRBuilderUtils.newJobId(MRBuilderUtils.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceInit(MRAppMaster.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$6.run(MRAppMaster.java:1737)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1734)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1668)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RecordFactoryPBImpl.newRecordInstance(RecordFactoryPBImpl.java:70)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/proto/MRProtos$JobIdProto$Builder.setAppId(Lorg/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto$Builder;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/proto/MRProtos$JobIdProto$Builder; @30: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/hadoop/shaded/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @30
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/proto/MRProtos$JobIdProto$Builder', 'org/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto$Builder' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/hadoop/shaded/com/google/protobuf/SingleFieldBuilder', 'org/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0073 c700 122a 2bb6 00ff b500 5a2a
    0x0000010: b600 f7a7 000f 2ab4 0073 2bb6 00ff b600
    0x0000020: fb57 2a59 b400 7904 80b5 0079 2ab0     
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@22)
    same_frame(@34)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.proto.MRProtos$JobIdProto.newBuilder(MRProtos.java:1017)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.records.impl.pb.JobIdPBImpl.<init>(JobIdPBImpl.java:37)
    ... 15 more
2018-01-03 00:05:31,877 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RecordFactoryPBImpl.newRecordInstance(RecordFactoryPBImpl.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.Records.newRecord(Records.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRBuilderUtils.newJobId(MRBuilderUtils.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceInit(MRAppMaster.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$6.run(MRAppMaster.java:1737)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1734)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1668)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RecordFactoryPBImpl.newRecordInstance(RecordFactoryPBImpl.java:70)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/proto/MRProtos$JobIdProto$Builder.setAppId(Lorg/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto$Builder;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/proto/MRProtos$JobIdProto$Builder; @30: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/hadoop/shaded/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @30
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/proto/MRProtos$JobIdProto$Builder', 'org/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto$Builder' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/hadoop/shaded/com/google/protobuf/SingleFieldBuilder', 'org/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0073 c700 122a 2bb6 00ff b500 5a2a
    0x0000010: b600 f7a7 000f 2ab4 0073 2bb6 00ff b600
    0x0000020: fb57 2a59 b400 7904 80b5 0079 2ab0     
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@22)
    same_frame(@34)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.proto.MRProtos$JobIdProto.newBuilder(MRProtos.java:1017)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.records.impl.pb.JobIdPBImpl.<init>(JobIdPBImpl.java:37)
    ... 15 more
2018-01-03 00:05:31,878 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

I have done some research, and related questions seem to suggest this is related to conflicting libraries in the classpath. (Eg: [Hadoop 2.6.0: Basic error "starting MRAppMaster" after installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791518/hadoop-2-6-0-basic-error-starting-mrappmaster-after-installing))

While that is not the case for me, my classpath (shown below) does not seem to include any hadoop library. (This is printed from within the Java class I am running, so it's using the classpath variable loaded during the hadoop execution)

```
/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:
/usr/lib64:
/lib64:
/lib:
/usr/lib
```

Any advice?

I am using Hadoop 3.0.0.

My class:

```
package uk.me.dariosdesk.hadoopTest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class TestWordCount {

    public static class TokenizerMapper
            extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(itr.nextToken());
                context.write(word, one);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class IntSumReducer
            extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
        private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                           Context context
        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
            }
            result.set(sum);
            context.write(key, result);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.err.println( (System.getProperty("java.library.path") ));
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
        job.setJarByClass(TestWordCount.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        System.out.println(args[1] + " " + args[2]);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the example app and did that succeed?

```
hadoop jar /opt/hadoop/current/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.0.0.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

One way to ensure that you don't have conflicting version of yarn in your class path is to execute this command

```
hadoop classpath
```

Output should be something like this

```
/opt/hadoop/current/etc/hadoop:/opt/hadoop/current/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/opt/hadoop/current/share/hadoop/common/*:/opt/hadoop/current/share/hadoop/hdfs:/opt/hadoop/current/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/opt/hadoop/current/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/opt/hadoop/current/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/opt/hadoop/current/share/hadoop/yarn:/opt/hadoop/current/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/opt/hadoop/current/share/hadoop/yarn/*
```

I had the same error when I was running the examples after installing hadoop 3. In my case hadoop class path command showed a version of hadoop added in my class path (via homebrew) which was older version (2.8.2). After I removed that I was able to run example successfully.

Additionally I had to add the following properties also to mapped-site.xml. I don't think this is related to class not found error but jobs were not getting executed successfully without it. Hope it helps.

```
   <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
    <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop/current</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
     <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop/current</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
     <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop/current</value>
   </property>
```

Comment: Sorry please ignore. The error that I was getting was class not found but a different class (ResourceUtils). On reading your problem more carefully I realize your error is slightly different. All the best.